# Docker compose builds unknown warnings, tables and roles

Tags: django

I need help understanding why my Django App is giving me a long log while hosting the database. The boilerplate is available here: https://github.com/trouchet/tarzan. Please, I am studying and want a remote job, and not be a local attendant in a cafe.

As you can see, the app builds and ups as expected, with the following issues, from my perspective:

1. **Unknown warning**: `WARN[0000] The "d" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string`;
2. **Unknown database roles and tables**: It starts with the snippet below and goes beyond with several unknown issues.

```
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:28.990 UTC [75] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "newrelic"
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:28.990 UTC [75] DETAIL:  Role "newrelic" does not exist.
tarzan-memory  |    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:36.180 UTC [71] ERROR:  relation "qrtz_scheduler_state" does not exist at character 15
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:36.180 UTC [71] STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'MetabaseScheduler'
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:36.180 UTC [72] ERROR:  relation "qrtz_triggers" does not exist at character 67
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:36.180 UTC [72] STATEMENT:  SELECT TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, PRIORITY FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'MetabaseScheduler' AND TRIGGER_STATE = $1 AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME <= $2 AND (MISFIRE_INSTR = -1 OR (MISFIRE_INSTR != -1 AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME >= $3)) ORDER BY NEXT_FIRE_TIME ASC, PRIORITY DESC
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:36.181 UTC [71] ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:36.181 UTC [71] STATEMENT:  
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:36.181 UTC [72] ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
tarzan-memory  | 2023-09-13 17:48:36.181 UTC [72] STATEMENT:
```

I consider myself a junior, so please, be kind to me.